# Storm dprc thrift7.transport.TTransportException: Frame size (1213486160) larger than max length (1048576)!

Tags: exception, thrift, apache-storm

I use storm 0.10.0 deploy `DRPCTopology` to storm cluster, but have `TTransportException`.

The code is:

```
DRPCClient client = new DRPCClient(map, "10.10.5.92", 3774, 5000);
System.out.println(client.execute("match-drpc", "cat"));
```

The error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.thrift7.transport.TTransportException: Frame size (1213486160) larger than max length (1048576)!
    at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TFramedTransport.readFrame(TFramedTransport.java:137)
    at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TFramedTransport.read(TFramedTransport.java:101)
    at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
    at org.apache.thrift7.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.thrift7.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
    at org.apache.thrift7.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
    at org.apache.thrift7.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
    at backtype.storm.generated.DistributedRPC$Client.recv_execute(DistributedRPC.java:106)
    at backtype.storm.generated.DistributedRPC$Client.execute(DistributedRPC.java:92)
    at backtype.storm.utils.DRPCClient.execute(DRPCClient.java:59)
```

Answer (score 4):

1213486160 is not an actual packet length. It is ASCII "HTTP" interpreted as a 32-bit big-endian integer. Your "DRPCClient" is not speaking the protocol you expect, but is instead a web server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase `nimbus.thrift.max_buffer_size` in your `storm.yaml` file. Afterwards, restart the cluster (otherwise, the new value is not considered).

Comment: Which `storm.yaml` did you update? Can you check the parameter in WebUI (it shows the parameters Nimbus picked up).

Comment: Yes  storm webUI   it change ,but not work at version 0.10.0  .   I use storm  0.9.6  instead

Comment: Seems you have a versions mixup... Did you install Storm by yourself? Or talk to your admin.

Comment: If StormUI shows larger value than 1213486160 for thrift buffer size and it still does not work, I habe no further idea how to resolve the issue... (maybe try to increase it to a power-of-two value.) what value did you configure? Still the exact same error as before?

Comment: Thanks! I have resolved ,when i delete all   disk & zookeeper data  , reinstall it , the err is gone .

Answer (score 1):

[STORM-1469](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-1469) is related to this problem, however its pull requests are not all merged, so the default transport plugin is still the old one (`SimpleTransportPlugin`).

Adding the following config fixed the problem in Storm v 1.0.2 for me (should work for 0.10.x as well).

`storm.thrift.transport: "org.apache.storm.security.auth.plain.PlainSaslTransportPlugin"`